# pecl install zip giving error ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, php

I am trying to install zip using  this command

```
pecl install zip
```

but I am getting below error

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root9LqSPb/zip-1.12.4/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root9LqSPb/zip-1.12.4/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root9LqSPb/zip-1.12.4/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c -o php_zip.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root9LqSPb/zip-1.12.4/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root9LqSPb/zip-1.12.4/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_zip.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c:30:0:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [php_zip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl compatible regular expressions - PCRE libraries is missing (...fatal error: pcre.h:...), because you are compiling module you should add dev packages too:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when `make` failed to build from sources, you have to install a `-dev` package, in your case it's `php5-dev`.

I'm not sure if it's the only one that you'll need to install but try first to install `php5-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```